# How to store a subclass that is not a direct subclass of "Document" in its own collection?

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine

As per MongoEngine Documentation on  [Document Inheritence](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/defining-documents.html#document-inheritance)

I tried to create a base class as below

```
import datetime
from mongoengine import *
connect("testdb")
class Base(Document):
   companyId = StringField(required=True)
   creationDate = DateTimeField()
   modifiedDate = DateTimeField()

   meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not self.creationDate:
           self.creationDate = datetime.datetime.now()
       self.modifiedDate = datetime.datetime.now()
       return super(Base, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

 class Child1(Base):
   #     identifier = StringField(required=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    createdBy = StringField(required=True)

 class Child2(Base):    
     memberId = StringField(required=True)

 Child1(companyId='ab', createdBy='123').save()
 Child2(companyId='ab', memberId='123').save()
```

MY aim is to get two collections named Child1 and Child2 under "testdb", but instead only one collection getting created named 'base' with two documents in it.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5656b66381f49543f27af85a"),
"_cls" : "Base.Child1",
"companyId" : "ab",
"creationDate" : ISODate("2015-11-26T13:06:01.689Z"),
"modifiedDate" : ISODate("2015-11-26T13:06:01.689Z"),
"createdBy" : "123"
}

/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5656b66381f49543f27af85b"),
"_cls" : "Base.Child2",
"companyId" : "ab",
"creationDate" : ISODate("2015-11-26T13:06:03.621Z"),
"modifiedDate" : ISODate("2015-11-26T13:06:03.621Z"),
"memberId" : "123"
}
```

How can I specify  different collection name for my subclass?

### versions

python 2.7.10

mongodb 3.0.3

mongoengine 0.8.7

pymongo 2.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour according to the [documentation](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/defining-documents.html#document-inheritance) you link.

> To create a specialised type of a Document you have defined, you may subclass it and add any extra fields or methods you may need. As this is new class is not a direct subclass of Document, it will not be stored in its own collection; it will use the same collection as its superclass uses.

That being said to store in it own collection you need the base class must be an abstract class and you can optionally specify the child class collections' name using their meta attribute.

```
class Base(Document):
   ...
   meta = {
       'allow_inheritance': True,
       'abstract': True
   }
   ...

class Child1(Base):    
    ...
    meta = {'collection': 'child1'} # optional
```